# How to list row values in a column based on grouping value in R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, transform, splitstackshape

Hej,

I have an input the file that has one column with gene id and then one with GO terms with multiple rows per gene (anywhere from 1 to >20). The format I need to generate has one single row for each unique gene id, with the GO terms in a second column, separated by semi-colons.

My data:

```
GeneID    GO
am1001    190909
am1001    600510
am1002    500050
am1002    432323
am1002    100209
```

The desired output:

```
GeneID    GO_list
am1001    190909; 600510
am1002    ​50050; 432323; 100209
```

I have tried things similar to [How to create new columns in a data.frame based on row values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906178/how-to-create-new-columns-in-a-data-frame-based-on-row-values-in-r) but was not successful.

Thanks in advance for your advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next `base R` approach:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(GeneID = c("am1001", "am1001", "am1002", "am1002", 
"am1002"), GO = c(190909L, 600510L, 500050L, 432323L, 100209L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The code:

```
#Aggregation
aggregate(GO~GeneID,data=df,FUN = function(x) paste0(x,collapse = '; '))
```

The output:

```
  GeneID                     GO
1 am1001         190909; 600510
2 am1002 500050; 432323; 100209
```